# How to prepare longitudinal data by Pandas to be then used from a learning algorithm?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I am using Pandas to clean and prepare my datasets to be used by a learning algorithm such as Random Forest for classification or K-means for Clustering.

I used to have datasets like this (illustrated example):

[image]

However, I am facing in such of my dataset a different type called: Longitudinal Data which is like the following illustrated example:

[image]

As you can see, for every single instance (person or car) has several values for the same feature where every value is added at a specific point of time.

This is an edited example from the dataset:

```
"ID","Temperature","***",
"001","36","***",
"001","36","***",
"001","37","***",
"001","36","***",
"002","38","***",
"002","38","***",
"002","36","***",
...
"004","37","***",
"004","37","***",
"005","36","***",
"005","36","***",
```

where every repeat for the same ID means a different day in which the data is taken- in our case the data is the Temperature.

How to use Pandas to prepare this kind of data to be useful for a learning algorithm such as Random Forest? If there is no way with Pandas, do you suggest a learning algorithm able to deal with such data? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post raw input data please

Comment: Hello Mr EdChum. It is nice to see you here. I have updated my question with a sample. Many thanks for your always positive and quick responses.

Comment: For starters, take a look at ```unstack()``` documentation.  This question would be easier for folks to answer if you also posted the desired final form of the data.

Comment: I just want to apologies to not thank you Mr JohnE for your response. I have put a similar question in the cross validated stack exchange with the hope that someone will find a solution from the perspective of machine learning way of using such structure in a suggested algorithm. Thank you for trying help, and sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to group partition on ID and then use any algorithm. This partitioning strategy will make sure that each ID (CustomerID etc) will stay in their respective training or test set.

Answer (score 0):

This Stack Overflow question has been asked for a very, very long time, but I would want to offer a very extensive answer to aid the community with this matter - or possibly the authors of the question, but given that it was asked seven years ago, I assume the authors have found a workaround.

You are working with longitudinal data, which is not what conventional machine learning algorithms are primarily centred on. As @greymatter stated, you may experiment with data transformation techniques to flatten your data, making it suitable for use with a conventional machine learning approach. The advantage of such an approach is that there are numerous machine learning techniques that can be used to your flattened data as a results of the data transformation procedure. However, this comes at the cost of losing the temporal context of your data, which could be disastrous if the time evolution of your data is crucial to consider (most of the time the case in healthcare-applied context).

In this instance, ML algorithm designers are recently increasingly focusing on algorithm adaptation. Algorithm adaption, modify an existing ML algorithm so that it can directly consider the temporal context of data without flattening it into a "static-based-format", hence, loosing the temporal context throughout the dataset. The advantage is that the time context is considered, but the disadvantage is that there are few viable algorithms. I am also incorporating, for the sake of simplicity, ML techniques specifically built for longitudinal data in that category, despite the fact that they are not adapted but rather designed from the bottom up to acquire time-indexed data.

In practice, there are numerous methods for flattening data, but [1] proposes three fundamental approaches for flattening its data in order to apply it to conventional ML algorithms. As illustrated in [1]'s first figure, the @greymatter strategy is included as methods for flattening your data in order to use traditional ML algorithms.

Therefore, for algorithm adaptation, below are a few proposals *[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]*, where the authors mostly altered (tree-based) standard ML algorithms to consider the temporal context / time progression of subjects through time. Consequently, this still requires transforming the data to be computationally computable, and [1] presents a final solution that transforms the data while retaining the time indices, enabling customised algorithm designers to trace the evolution through Time while designing new adapted algorithms.

This response intended solely to direct you towards the implementation of such data or to new readers. Machine learning x Longitudinal data is a pretty new scientific subject, and there is still much work to be done. Whereas Statistics x Longitudinal data is much older but here we focussed on ML rather than statistics to be clear. Hence, feel free to comment if you want additional information added to the answer for yourself or further readers.

In the hopes that this is of help, here are the references:

- [1] Ribeiro, C. and Freitas, A.A., 2019. A mini-survey of supervised machine learning approaches for coping with ageing-related longitudinal datasets. In 3rd Workshop on AI for Aging, Rehabilitation and Independent Assisted Living (ARIAL), held as part of IJCAI-2019 (p. 5).
  Vancouver
- [2] Ribeiro, C. and Freitas, A., 2020, December. A new random forest method for longitudinal data classification using a lexicographic bi-objective approach. In 2020 IEEE Symposium Series on Computational Intelligence (SSCI) (pp. 806-813). IEEE.
- [3] Ribeiro, C. and Freitas, A.A., 2021. A data-driven missing value imputation approach for longitudinal datasets. Artificial Intelligence Review, pp.1-31.
  Vancouver
- [4] Jie, B., Liu, M., Liu, J., Zhang, D. and Shen, D., 2016. Temporally constrained group sparse learning for longitudinal data analysis in Alzheimer's disease. IEEE Transactions on Biomedical Engineering, 64(1), pp.238-249.
  Vancouver
- [5] Du, W., Cheung, H., Johnson, C.A., Goldberg, I., Thambisetty, M. and Becker, K., 2015, November. A longitudinal support vector regression for prediction of ALS score. In 2015 IEEE International Conference on Bioinformatics and Biomedicine (BIBM) (pp. 1586-1590). IEEE.
  Vancouver
- [6] Adhikari, S., Lecci, F., Becker, J.T., Junker, B.W., Kuller, L.H., Lopez, O.L. and Tibshirani, R.J., 2019. High‐dimensional longitudinal classification with the multinomial fused lasso. Statistics in medicine, 38(12), pp.2184-2205.
  Vancouver
- [7] Huang, L., Jin, Y., Gao, Y., Thung, K.H., Shen, D. and Alzheimer's Disease Neuroimaging Initiative, 2016. Longitudinal clinical score prediction in Alzheimer's disease with soft-split sparse regression based random forest. Neurobiology of aging, 46, pp.180-191.
  Vancouver
- [8] Radovic, M., Ghalwash, M., Filipovic, N. and Obradovic, Z., 2017. Minimum redundancy maximum relevance feature selection approach for temporal gene expression data. BMC bioinformatics, 18(1), pp.1-14.
  Vancouver
- [9] Pomsuwan, T. and Freitas, A.A., 2017, November. Feature selection for the classification of longitudinal human ageing data. In 2017 IEEE International Conference on Data Mining Workshops (ICDMW) (pp. 739-746). IEEE. Vancouver
- [10] Ovchinnik, S., Otero, F. and Freitas, A.A., 2022, April. Nested trees for longitudinal classification. In Proceedings of the 37th ACM/SIGAPP Symposium on Applied Computing (pp. 441-444).
  Vancouver

*For more, follow the community thought google scholar, by typing longitudinal data classification.*